# Objective-C Incompatible pointer types initializing 'XYZShoutingPerson *' with an expression of type 'XYZPerson *'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm going through the [Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW24) tutorial, and I've arrived at trying to implement the class factory method for XYZPerson

Everything looks OK until I try instantiating an object with the child class called XYZShoutingPerson. I get the following error inside `main.m`

Incompatible pointer types initializing 'XYZShoutingPerson *' with an expression of type 'XYZPerson *'

XYZPerson.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface XYZPerson : NSObject

@property NSString *firstName;
@property NSString *lastName;
@property NSDate *dateOfBirth;

+ (XYZPerson *)person;

- (void)sayHello;
- (void)saySomething:(NSString *)greeting;

@end
```

XYZPerson.m

```
    #import "XYZPerson.h"

    @implementation XYZPerson

    + (id)person
    {
        return [[self alloc] init];
    }

    - (void)sayHello
    {
        [self saySomething:@"Hello, World!"];
    }

    - (void)saySomething:(NSString *)greeting
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", greeting);
    }

    @end
```

XYZShoutingPerson.h

```
#import "XYZPerson.h"

@interface XYZShoutingPerson : XYZPerson
@end
```

XYZShoutingPerson.m

```
 #import "XYZShoutingPerson.h"

    @implementation XYZShoutingPerson

    - (void)saySomething:(NSString *)greeting
    {
        NSString *uppercaseGreeting = [greeting uppercaseString];
        [super saySomething:uppercaseGreeting];
    }

    @end
```

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>   
#import "XYZPerson.h"
#import "XYZShoutingPerson.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        XYZPerson *newPerson = [XYZPerson person];
        [newPerson sayHello];
        XYZShoutingPerson *shoutingPerson = [XYZShoutingPerson person];
        [shoutingPerson sayHello];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is you are downcasting `XYZPerson` to `XYZShoutingPerson`, which need explicit cast.

What you should do is change the method return type so it matches.

`+ (XYZPerson *)person;` should be `+ (instancetype)person;`

see http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#objective-c-features for more details